# print array as a matrix by having all elements in the right columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, output

I am trying to print my dataframe as a matrix. To do so, I want to use an array. To be clear:

I have a dictionary, Y, which is like this:

```
{(0, 0): {(0, 0): 0, (1, 0): 1, (0, 1): 1, (0, 2): 2, (0, 3): 3, (1, 3): 4, (0, 4): 10, (1, 4): 9, (0, 5): 11, (1, 1): 2, (1, 2): 5, (2, 2): 6, (2, 4): 8, (1, 5): 10, (2, 0): 10, (3, 0): 9, (2, 1): 7, (3, 1): 8, (3, 2): 7, (2, 3): 7, (3, 4): 9, (2, 5): 9, (3, 5): 10, (3, 3): 8}, (1, 0): {(1, 0): 0, (0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (0, 3): 4, (1, 3): 5, (0, 4): 11, (1, 4): 10, (0, 5): 12, (1, 2): 6, (2, 2): 7, (2, 4): 9, (1, 5): 11, (2, 0): 11, (3, 0): 10, (2, 1): 8, (3, 1): 9, (3, 2): 8, (2, 3): 8, (3, 4): 10, (2, 5): 10, (3, 5): 11, (3, 3): 9}, (0, 1): {(0, 1): 0, (0, 0): 1, (0, 2): 1, (1, 0): 2, (0, 3): 2, (1, 3): 3, (0, 4): 9, (1, 4): 8, (0, 5): 10, (1, 1): 3, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 5, (2, 4): 7, (1, 5): 9, (2, 0): 9, (3, 0): 8, (2, 1): 6, (3, 1): 7, (3, 2): 6, (2, 3): 6, (3, 4): 8, (2, 5): 8, (3, 5): 9, (3, 3): 7}, (0, 2): {(0, 2): 0, (0, 1): 1, (0, 3): 1, (0, 0): 2, (1, 0): 3, (1, 3): 2, (0, 4): 8, (1, 4): 7, (0, 5): 9, (1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 3, (2, 2): 4, (2, 4): 6, (1, 5): 8, (2, 0): 8, (3, 0): 7, (2, 1): 5, (3, 1): 6, (3, 2): 5, (2, 3): 5, (3, 4): 7, (2, 5): 7, (3, 5): 8, (3, 3): 6}, (0, 3): {(0, 3): 0, (0, 2): 1, (1, 3): 1, (0, 0): 3, (1, 0): 4, (0, 1): 2, (0, 4): 7, (1, 4): 6, (0, 5): 8, (1, 1): 5, (1, 2): 2, (2, 2): 3, (2, 4): 5, (1, 5): 7, (2, 0): 7, (3, 0): 6, (2, 1): 4, (3, 1): 5, (3, 2): 4, (2, 3): 4, (3, 4): 6, (2, 5): 6, (3, 5): 7, (3, 3): 5}, (1, 3): {(1, 3): 0, (0, 3): 1, (1, 2): 1, (0, 0): 4, (1, 0): 5, (0, 1): 3, (0, 2): 2, (0, 4): 6, (1, 4): 5, (0, 5): 7, (1, 1): 6, (2, 2): 2, (2, 4): 4, (1, 5): 6, (2, 0): 6, (3, 0): 5, (2, 1): 3, (3, 1): 4, (3, 2): 3, (2, 3): 3, (3, 4): 5, (2, 5): 5, (3, 5): 6, (3, 3): 4}, (0, 4): {(0, 4): 0, (1, 4): 1, (0, 5): 1, (0, 0): 10, (1, 0): 11, (0, 1): 9, (0, 2): 8, (0, 3): 7, (1, 3): 6, (1, 1): 12, (1, 2): 5, (2, 2): 4, (2, 4): 2, (1, 5): 2, (2, 0): 8, (3, 0): 7, (2, 1): 5, (3, 1): 6, (3, 2): 5, (2, 3): 3, (3, 4): 3, (2, 5): 3, (3, 5): 4, (3, 3): 6}, (1, 4): {(1, 4): 0, (0, 4): 1, (2, 4): 1, (1, 5): 1, (0, 0): 9, (1, 0): 10, (0, 1): 8, (0, 2): 7, (0, 3): 6, (1, 3): 5, (0, 5): 2, (1, 1): 11, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 3, (2, 0): 7, (3, 0): 6, (2, 1): 4, (3, 1): 5, (3, 2): 4, (2, 3): 2, (3, 4): 2, (2, 5): 2, (3, 5): 3, (3, 3): 5}, (0, 5): {(0, 5): 0, (0, 4): 1, (0, 0): 11, (1, 0): 12, (0, 1): 10, (0, 2): 9, (0, 3): 8, (1, 3): 7, (1, 4): 2, (1, 1): 13, (1, 2): 6, (2, 2): 5, (2, 4): 3, (1, 5): 3, (2, 0): 9, (3, 0): 8, (2, 1): 6, (3, 1): 7, (3, 2): 6, (2, 3): 4, (3, 4): 4, (2, 5): 4, (3, 5): 5, (3, 3): 7}, (1, 1): {(1, 1): 0, (1, 0): 1, (0, 0): 2, (0, 1): 3, (0, 2): 4, (0, 3): 5, (1, 3): 6, (0, 4): 12, (1, 4): 11, (0, 5): 13, (1, 2): 7, (2, 2): 8, (2, 4): 10, (1, 5): 12, (2, 0): 12, (3, 0): 11, (2, 1): 9, (3, 1): 10, (3, 2): 9, (2, 3): 9, (3, 4): 11, (2, 5): 11, (3, 5): 12, (3, 3): 10}, (1, 2): {(1, 2): 0, (1, 3): 1, (2, 2): 1, (0, 0): 5, (1, 0): 6, (0, 1): 4, (0, 2): 3, (0, 3): 2, (0, 4): 5, (1, 4): 4, (0, 5): 6, (1, 1): 7, (2, 4): 3, (1, 5): 5, (2, 0): 5, (3, 0): 4, (2, 1): 2, (3, 1): 3, (3, 2): 2, (2, 3): 2, (3, 4): 4, (2, 5): 4, (3, 5): 5, (3, 3): 3}, (2, 2): {(2, 2): 0, (1, 2): 1, (2, 1): 1, (3, 2): 1, (2, 3): 1, (0, 0): 6, (1, 0): 7, (0, 1): 5, (0, 2): 4, (0, 3): 3, (1, 3): 2, (0, 4): 4, (1, 4): 3, (0, 5): 5, (1, 1): 8, (2, 4): 2, (1, 5): 4, (2, 0): 4, (3, 0): 3, (3, 1): 2, (3, 4): 3, (2, 5): 3, (3, 5): 4, (3, 3): 2}, (2, 4): {(2, 4): 0, (1, 4): 1, (2, 3): 1, (3, 4): 1, (2, 5): 1, (0, 0): 8, (1, 0): 9, (0, 1): 7, (0, 2): 6, (0, 3): 5, (1, 3): 4, (0, 4): 2, (0, 5): 3, (1, 1): 10, (1, 2): 3, (2, 2): 2, (1, 5): 2, (2, 0): 6, (3, 0): 5, (2, 1): 3, (3, 1): 4, (3, 2): 3, (3, 5): 2, (3, 3): 4}, (1, 5): {(1, 5): 0, (1, 4): 1, (0, 0): 10, (1, 0): 11, (0, 1): 9, (0, 2): 8, (0, 3): 7, (1, 3): 6, (0, 4): 2, (0, 5): 3, (1, 1): 12, (1, 2): 5, (2, 2): 4, (2, 4): 2, (2, 0): 8, (3, 0): 7, (2, 1): 5, (3, 1): 6, (3, 2): 5, (2, 3): 3, (3, 4): 3, (2, 5): 3, (3, 5): 4, (3, 3): 6}, (2, 0): {(2, 0): 0, (3, 0): 1, (0, 0): 10, (1, 0): 11, (0, 1): 9, (0, 2): 8, (0, 3): 7, (1, 3): 6, (0, 4): 8, (1, 4): 7, (0, 5): 9, (1, 1): 12, (1, 2): 5, (2, 2): 4, (2, 4): 6, (1, 5): 8, (2, 1): 3, (3, 1): 2, (3, 2): 5, (2, 3): 5, (3, 4): 7, (2, 5): 7, (3, 5): 8, (3, 3): 6}, (3, 0): {(3, 0): 0, (2, 0): 1, (3, 1): 1, (0, 0): 9, (1, 0): 10, (0, 1): 8, (0, 2): 7, (0, 3): 6, (1, 3): 5, (0, 4): 7, (1, 4): 6, (0, 5): 8, (1, 1): 11, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 3, (2, 4): 5, (1, 5): 7, (2, 1): 2, (3, 2): 4, (2, 3): 4, (3, 4): 6, (2, 5): 6, (3, 5): 7, (3, 3): 5}, (2, 1): {(2, 1): 0, (2, 2): 1, (3, 1): 1, (0, 0): 7, (1, 0): 8, (0, 1): 6, (0, 2): 5, (0, 3): 4, (1, 3): 3, (0, 4): 5, (1, 4): 4, (0, 5): 6, (1, 1): 9, (1, 2): 2, (2, 4): 3, (1, 5): 5, (2, 0): 3, (3, 0): 2, (3, 2): 2, (2, 3): 2, (3, 4): 4, (2, 5): 4, (3, 5): 5, (3, 3): 3}, (3, 1): {(3, 1): 0, (3, 0): 1, (2, 1): 1, (0, 0): 8, (1, 0): 9, (0, 1): 7, (0, 2): 6, (0, 3): 5, (1, 3): 4, (0, 4): 6, (1, 4): 5, (0, 5): 7, (1, 1): 10, (1, 2): 3, (2, 2): 2, (2, 4): 4, (1, 5): 6, (2, 0): 2, (3, 2): 3, (2, 3): 3, (3, 4): 5, (2, 5): 5, (3, 5): 6, (3, 3): 4}, (3, 2): {(3, 2): 0, (2, 2): 1, (3, 3): 1, (0, 0): 7, (1, 0): 8, (0, 1): 6, (0, 2): 5, (0, 3): 4, (1, 3): 3, (0, 4): 5, (1, 4): 4, (0, 5): 6, (1, 1): 9, (1, 2): 2, (2, 4): 3, (1, 5): 5, (2, 0): 5, (3, 0): 4, (2, 1): 2, (3, 1): 3, (2, 3): 2, (3, 4): 4, (2, 5): 4, (3, 5): 5}, (2, 3): {(2, 3): 0, (2, 2): 1, (2, 4): 1, (0, 0): 7, (1, 0): 8, (0, 1): 6, (0, 2): 5, (0, 3): 4, (1, 3): 3, (0, 4): 3, (1, 4): 2, (0, 5): 4, (1, 1): 9, (1, 2): 2, (1, 5): 3, (2, 0): 5, (3, 0): 4, (2, 1): 2, (3, 1): 3, (3, 2): 2, (3, 4): 2, (2, 5): 2, (3, 5): 3, (3, 3): 3}, (3, 4): {(3, 4): 0, (2, 4): 1, (0, 0): 9, (1, 0): 10, (0, 1): 8, (0, 2): 7, (0, 3): 6, (1, 3): 5, (0, 4): 3, (1, 4): 2, (0, 5): 4, (1, 1): 11, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 3, (1, 5): 3, (2, 0): 7, (3, 0): 6, (2, 1): 4, (3, 1): 5, (3, 2): 4, (2, 3): 2, (2, 5): 2, (3, 5): 3, (3, 3): 5}, (2, 5): {(2, 5): 0, (2, 4): 1, (3, 5): 1, (0, 0): 9, (1, 0): 10, (0, 1): 8, (0, 2): 7, (0, 3): 6, (1, 3): 5, (0, 4): 3, (1, 4): 2, (0, 5): 4, (1, 1): 11, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 3, (1, 5): 3, (2, 0): 7, (3, 0): 6, (2, 1): 4, (3, 1): 5, (3, 2): 4, (2, 3): 2, (3, 4): 2, (3, 3): 5}, (3, 5): {(3, 5): 0, (2, 5): 1, (0, 0): 10, (1, 0): 11, (0, 1): 9, (0, 2): 8, (0, 3): 7, (1, 3): 6, (0, 4): 4, (1, 4): 3, (0, 5): 5, (1, 1): 12, (1, 2): 5, (2, 2): 4, (2, 4): 2, (1, 5): 4, (2, 0): 8, (3, 0): 7, (2, 1): 5, (3, 1): 6, (3, 2): 5, (2, 3): 3, (3, 4): 3, (3, 3): 6}, (3, 3): {(3, 3): 0, (3, 2): 1, (0, 0): 8, (1, 0): 9, (0, 1): 7, (0, 2): 6, (0, 3): 5, (1, 3): 4, (0, 4): 6, (1, 4): 5, (0, 5): 7, (1, 1): 10, (1, 2): 3, (2, 2): 2, (2, 4): 4, (1, 5): 6, (2, 0): 6, (3, 0): 5, (2, 1): 3, (3, 1): 4, (2, 3): 3, (3, 4): 5, (2, 5): 5, (3, 5): 6}}
```

Using pandas I converted the dictionary to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Y)
df.index = [*df.index]
df.columns = [*df.columns]
arraydf = df.to_numpy()
```

This is the dataframe I get:

```
        (0, 0)  (1, 0)  (0, 1)  (0, 2)  ...  (3, 4)  (2, 5)  (3, 5)  (3, 3)
(0, 0)       0       1       1       2  ...       9       9      10       8
(1, 0)       1       0       2       3  ...      10      10      11       9
(0, 1)       1       2       0       1  ...       8       8       9       7
(0, 2)       2       3       1       0  ...       7       7       8       6
(0, 3)       3       4       2       1  ...       6       6       7       5
(1, 3)       4       5       3       2  ...       5       5       6       4
(0, 4)      10      11       9       8  ...       3       3       4       6
(1, 4)       9      10       8       7  ...       2       2       3       5
(0, 5)      11      12      10       9  ...       4       4       5       7
(1, 1)       2       1       3       4  ...      11      11      12      10
(1, 2)       5       6       4       3  ...       4       4       5       3
(2, 2)       6       7       5       4  ...       3       3       4       2
(2, 4)       8       9       7       6  ...       1       1       2       4
(1, 5)      10      11       9       8  ...       3       3       4       6
(2, 0)      10      11       9       8  ...       7       7       8       6
(3, 0)       9      10       8       7  ...       6       6       7       5
(2, 1)       7       8       6       5  ...       4       4       5       3
(3, 1)       8       9       7       6  ...       5       5       6       4
(3, 2)       7       8       6       5  ...       4       4       5       1
(2, 3)       7       8       6       5  ...       2       2       3       3
(3, 4)       9      10       8       7  ...       0       2       3       5
(2, 5)       9      10       8       7  ...       2       0       1       5
(3, 5)      10      11       9       8  ...       3       1       0       6
(3, 3)       8       9       7       6  ...       5       5       6       0
```

Then, I convert the df to an array:

```
arraydf = df.to_numpy()
```

This is my output now:

```
[ 0  1  1  2  3  4 10  9 11  2  5  6  8 10 10  9  7  8  7  7  9  9 10  8]
[ 1  0  2  3  4  5 11 10 12  1  6  7  9 11 11 10  8  9  8  8 10 10 11  9]
[ 1  2  0  1  2  3  9  8 10  3  4  5  7  9  9  8  6  7  6  6  8  8  9  7]
[2 3 1 0 1 2 8 7 9 4 3 4 6 8 8 7 5 6 5 5 7 7 8 6]
[3 4 2 1 0 1 7 6 8 5 2 3 5 7 7 6 4 5 4 4 6 6 7 5]
[4 5 3 2 1 0 6 5 7 6 1 2 4 6 6 5 3 4 3 3 5 5 6 4]
[10 11  9  8  7  6  0  1  1 12  5  4  2  2  8  7  5  6  5  3  3  3  4  6]
[ 9 10  8  7  6  5  1  0  2 11  4  3  1  1  7  6  4  5  4  2  2  2  3  5]
[11 12 10  9  8  7  1  2  0 13  6  5  3  3  9  8  6  7  6  4  4  4  5  7]
[ 2  1  3  4  5  6 12 11 13  0  7  8 10 12 12 11  9 10  9  9 11 11 12 10]
[5 6 4 3 2 1 5 4 6 7 0 1 3 5 5 4 2 3 2 2 4 4 5 3]
[6 7 5 4 3 2 4 3 5 8 1 0 2 4 4 3 1 2 1 1 3 3 4 2]
[ 8  9  7  6  5  4  2  1  3 10  3  2  0  2  6  5  3  4  3  1  1  1  2  4]
[10 11  9  8  7  6  2  1  3 12  5  4  2  0  8  7  5  6  5  3  3  3  4  6]
[10 11  9  8  7  6  8  7  9 12  5  4  6  8  0  1  3  2  5  5  7  7  8  6]
[ 9 10  8  7  6  5  7  6  8 11  4  3  5  7  1  0  2  1  4  4  6  6  7  5]
[7 8 6 5 4 3 5 4 6 9 2 1 3 5 3 2 0 1 2 2 4 4 5 3]
[ 8  9  7  6  5  4  6  5  7 10  3  2  4  6  2  1  1  0  3  3  5  5  6  4]
[7 8 6 5 4 3 5 4 6 9 2 1 3 5 5 4 2 3 0 2 4 4 5 1]
[7 8 6 5 4 3 3 2 4 9 2 1 1 3 5 4 2 3 2 0 2 2 3 3]
[ 9 10  8  7  6  5  3  2  4 11  4  3  1  3  7  6  4  5  4  2  0  2  3  5]
[ 9 10  8  7  6  5  3  2  4 11  4  3  1  3  7  6  4  5  4  2  2  0  1  5]
[10 11  9  8  7  6  4  3  5 12  5  4  2  4  8  7  5  6  5  3  3  1  0  6]
[ 8  9  7  6  5  4  6  5  7 10  3  2  4  6  6  5  3  4  1  3  5  5  6  0]
```

My question is: **How can I get the final array to seem a matrix?** I want all the lines of the same lenghts and to be in the right order (have "nice" readable columns also)

EDIT:
asked infos:

```
arraydf.shape
(24, 24)

arraydf.dtype
int64

df.dtypes
(0, 0)    int64
(0, 1)    int64
(0, 2)    int64
(1, 2)    int64
(0, 3)    int64
(0, 4)    int64
(1, 4)    int64
(0, 5)    int64
(1, 5)    int64
(1, 0)    int64
(2, 0)    int64
(1, 1)    int64
(1, 3)    int64
(2, 3)    int64
(3, 0)    int64
(2, 1)    int64
(2, 2)    int64
(2, 4)    int64
(2, 5)    int64
(3, 5)    int64
(3, 1)    int64
(3, 2)    int64
(3, 3)    int64
(3, 4)    int64
dtype: object

df.info
<bound method DataFrame.info of         (0, 0)  (0, 1)  (0, 2)  (1, 2)  ...  (3, 1)  (3, 2)  (3, 3)  (3, 4)
(0, 0)       0       1       2       3  ...       8       9      10      11
(0, 1)       1       0       1       2  ...       7       8       9      10
(0, 2)       2       1       0       1  ...       6       7       8       9
(1, 2)       3       2       1       0  ...       5       6       7       8
(0, 3)       3       2       1       2  ...       7       8       9      10
(0, 4)       4       3       2       3  ...       8       9      10      11
(1, 4)       5       4       3       4  ...       9      10      11      12
(0, 5)       5       4       3       4  ...       9      10      11      12
(1, 5)       6       5       4       5  ...      10      11      12      13
(1, 0)       5       4       3       2  ...       3       4       5       6
(2, 0)       6       5       4       3  ...       2       3       4       5
(1, 1)       4       3       2       1  ...       4       5       6       7
(1, 3)       4       3       2       1  ...       6       7       8       9
(2, 3)       5       4       3       2  ...       7       8       9      10
(3, 0)       7       6       5       4  ...       1       2       3       4
(2, 1)       7       6       5       4  ...       3       4       5       6
(2, 2)       8       7       6       5  ...       4       5       6       7
(2, 4)      14      13      12      11  ...       6       5       4       3
(2, 5)      13      12      11      10  ...       5       4       3       2
(3, 5)      12      11      10       9  ...       4       3       2       1
(3, 1)       8       7       6       5  ...       0       1       2       3
(3, 2)       9       8       7       6  ...       1       0       1       2
(3, 3)      10       9       8       7  ...       2       1       0       1
(3, 4)      11      10       9       8  ...       3       2       1       0
```

Comment: Show `arraydf.shape` and `arraydf.dtype`.  `df.dtypes` or `df.info` might also help.  It's not so much a matter of `printing right` as understanding what you have.  We don't have much control over the display of an array, but we can control the array's nature.

Comment: How are you printing the array?  WIth `print(arraydf)` or with a row by row loop?  While it took a bit fiddling to copy-n-paste your `Y`, I get a nice (24,24) shape array (same before and after your reindexing).

Comment: I'm using a row by row loop. I have to use it for another thing I have to do (not really related to the question, so I didn't write it)

Comment: Columns can't be aligned in a row by row print; each is formatted by itself.  It's the whole array print that aligns columns.  Now if you writing to a `csv` style file (`savetxt`) you can control line layout.  (Well, you could do the same formatted line print - just treat the row as a Python list and use standard Python print formatting.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand... which methods are you advising me to use?
Later I'll have to print each row one by one in pygame...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpt6M.png Later I'll need to print it, but not like this

Comment: I'm advising you use basic python string formatting, since you can't, or just won't use the simplest numpy display option.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't want it in terminal, but in a pygame window...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print line-by-line and still have things aligned you can do the following:

```
>>> for l in str(df.to_numpy()).split("\n"):
...     print(l)
... 
[[ 0  1  1  2  3  4 10  9 11  2  5  6  8 10 10  9  7  8  7  7  9  9 10  8]
 [ 1  2  0  1  2  3  9  8 10  3  4  5  7  9  9  8  6  7  6  6  8  8  9  7]
 [ 2  3  1  0  1  2  8  7  9  4  3  4  6  8  8  7  5  6  5  5  7  7  8  6]
 [ 3  4  2  1  0  1  7  6  8  5  2  3  5  7  7  6  4  5  4  4  6  6  7  5]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the array look nice, then `pprint` is your friend (see [this nice article)](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-pretty-print-in-python-9b1d8764d151).

Comment: Can I save into an array the resut?

Comment: @hellomynameisA What is it you want? A nice print out or the data structure?

Comment: Both. I want to save it in a array and then, print the array row-by-row and have the nice printing

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpt6M.png Later I'll need to print it, but not like this

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to see it then use

```
print(df)
```

Pandas will display it so you know how the data looks. If you are using jupyter it will display in a fancy table which is why I like using a jupyter notebook when working with data frames/matrices.

Comment: I don't need to print like that... I need to save it in a certain format and then I'll print